zero values in dependent variable , correct structure of the data , zero-inflated model
I want to understand the relationship between macroeconomic variables and the fundraising volume for specific funds (secondary funds).
I got the following dataset (assume a table:
1.
Fundname:
Abbott Secondary Opportunities III LP
Fundraising Date:
06/2024
Fund Size:
62 mio
2.
Fundname:
ABS Ventures VI, L.P.
Fundraising Date:
01/2004
Fund Size:
64 mio
...
I got 200 other funds between 2000 and 2024.
As independent variables I chose interest rate level, inflation rate, GDP index, IPO Volume and sp500 index for the specific period. So for instance I looked up the interest rate level for 06/2024 and 01/2004 and for 200 more funds between 2000 and 2024.
Now I dont know which type of regression should I use and how I should structure my regression.
If I do monthly regression, I will have 150 zero observations as dependent variable because there is no fundraising each month according to the data and some funds are raising money in the same period. for instance for 06/2024 my dependent variable would be 62mio, but for 05/2024 maybe zero...
Can I delete the zeros? Can I use a zero inflated model? But I dont know if you consider this data as count data?
Or is the following structure recommended?
I only include the months where I got information on fundraising (fundraising >0) So in this case I would directly jump from 06/2024 to 01/2004 because in between it would be zero (of course this example is exaggerated, there are funds in between but not every month...)

It depends on what you want to know, and why the values are zero.

If they're zero because an organization didn't report (and not because they didn't raise any funds), then I would drop these observations.
If you simply want to estimate the average amount of funds raised per month, you might be able to get away with a simple linear regression even though these zeros will make the residual distribution non-Gaussian (many of the properties of linear regression models don't depend on the error distribution being Gaussian, or depend weakly on the error distribution; economists use linear models for non-Gaussian data all the time).
If you want to treat the data more mechanistically, you can do a zero-inflated model with continuous responses, see this answer or Min and Agresti 2002 (ref below). In this case I would probably fit a logistic regression to "zero vs non-zero" and then a linear model (or log-linear or whatever) to the non-zero values.

I would not recommend treating this as a count data set.

Min, Yongyi, and Alan Agresti. “Modeling Nonnegative Data with Clumping at Zero: A Survey.” Journal of the Iranian Statistical Society 1, no. 1 (November 2002): 7–33.

Thank you very much! Is there any literature I can reference for your zero-inflated model with continuous approach? Another Idea I had was to use quarterly periods (currently it is monthly). In this way I could sum months with zeros and months with >0 and could smooth the observations (basically I would sum jan, feb and march to one quarter and so on)? Is this possible, altough I know that it might not be the best method? Is there any reference for this way of smoothing?
Thanks in advance

Section 2.2 of the Min and Agresti paper that I referred to in the linked answer (and possibly references therein) would seem to be a reasonable reference. Aggregating seems like a reasonable solution as well. Don't know of a reference.

Thanks agian, you saved my life. But I still do have anouther question.
If I would follow the approach you have mentioned, are there any regression diagnostics/ tests I have to do in order to get a good outcome? The paper does not provide the answer for this.
e.g:
Linearity: The relationship between X and the mean of Y is linear.
Homoscedasticity: The variance of residual is the same for any value of X.
Independence: Observations are independent of each other.
Normality: For any fixed value of X, Y is normally distributed.
Thanks again

Since you're essentially running two independent tests (one logistic and one linear regression), the assumptions on each test are standard (i.e. the assumptions/diagnostics for the linear regression on the positive values are whatever you would ordinarily use for a linear regression). (If the answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...)
